# Choosing a blender that can puree hard fruit (like coconut)

Tags: equipment, blender

I'm thinking about buying a blender since my food processor doesn't do a great job at pureeing tomatoes or blending my homemade almond milk. I'm considering buying a blender that can also puree fresh coconut if I can find one withing my budget. I'd like to spend 70€ tops. In my country (Portugal) I can find blenders with 1000W and 1200W within this price range. These are supposed to be high speed blenders, but for the blenders I'm seeing I can't find any reviews saying they can puree coconut. Will any blender over 1000w puree coconut? How can I know? Any advice?

Comment: Not a budget option but, blendtec has a specific jar called twister jar for these applications.

Comment: Thank you zetaprime, here in Portugal a Blendtec is out of my budget...